# Сколько аргументов можно передать в функцию и от чего это зависит?

Tags: c++, c

Всем привет. Собственно весь вопрос содержится в теме.
Второстепенный вопрос: какое наибольшее количество аргументов можно наиболее эффективно передать в функцию без накладных действий.
Жду ответы <3

Comment: Зависит от архитектуры и [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Например, в x86-64 6 первых целых передаются в регистрах

Comment: А это для чего вам это нужно? Просто интересно. Обычно в C вопрос решается передачей указателя на структуру. В C++ ещё проще с функциями-членами.

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован бессмысленно. Что такое "можно"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++ поддерживает объявление функции до **256** аргументов (это **минимум**, который должна реализовывать конкретная архитектура). Как правило, в функцию нежелательно пихать много аргументов.

Накладные расходы будут заметны в том случае, если будете рекурсивно вызывать эту функцию (stackoverflow наступит быстрее, если у функции будет больше аргументов).

Answer (score 5):

1. Не ясно, что такое "можно". Сколько компилятор разрешит? Или сколько правильно? Или сколько получится передать во время выполнения?

   Сколько аргументов компилятор вам разрешит передавать в функцию зависит от того, сколько параметров указано в объявлении функции. Сколько указано - столько и разрешит, ни больше, ни меньше.

   Исключениями являются функции с `...` параметрами в С и С++, функции с шаблонными parameter pack в C++ и функции, объявленные без прототипа в С. В них можно передавать любое количество аргументов (вплоть до ограничений реализации, если они есть).

   Однако в случае функций, объявленных без прототипа в С, передача неправильного количества аргументов приведет к неопределенному поведению.

   Сколько аргументов получится передать во время выполнения зависит, разумеется, от физического размера каждого аргумента.
2. Не ясно, что такое "эффективно".

   Если речь идет о передаче через регистры процессора, то это зависит от количества регистров процессора и принятых на данной платформе соглашениях о вызове.